# How to add a line break inside with CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress site and attempting to break a "Read more" link to a new line. The code is **automatically generated** through a widget, so I **cannot** simply add a break or paragraph tag :(

This *could* be done by simply putting a class rule of `display:block` *but* my issue is that my link style uses a background color, so using `block` makes it look like crap (since it spans the full width).

**Code :**

```
<div>Post excerpt is here ... <a href="url" class="more-link">Read More</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the link to behave like a table. It then becomes to a block level element, also keeps the minimum width.

```css
.more-link {
  display: table;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
Post excerpt is here ... <a href="url" class="more-link">Read More</a>
```

You can also insert a line break with a pseudo element.

```css
.more-link {
  background: gold;
}

.more-link:before {
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
Post excerpt is here ... <a href="url" class="more-link">Read More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should insert your read more text within a new `<p>` tag if you would like it on a new line, and keep your code nice and clean.

Then as you say you have a background style applied, you could then put it inside a `<span>` or some other tag that isn't block based.

Comment: Code is automatically generated :(

Comment: You can override it within your themes functions.php file

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good chance you'll need to get under the hood and adjust some php to do it right...

First [Check out the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

You'll probably need to add something like:

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
function modify_read_more_link() {
  return '<br><a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Link Text...</a>';
}
```

to your functions.php file.

[Please be sure to read the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More), don't just copy and paste the code, different setups (child themes and so on) may need slightly different code.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there might be a css tweak. I know PHP, but I *didn't* want to edit the plug-in unless I really had to. I think it'll be just a matter of concatenating in a <br/> tag :(

Comment: @MichaelRoach Your options will probably be adjusting the position, float, or display... seems like it may be a kludge way to do it though.